# Javascript giving two different results for the same thing. Accessing arrays using a numeral and a variable

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  pages = new Array(4);
  pages[0] = "here";
  pages[1] = "is";
  pages[2] = "some";
  pages[3] = "data";
  
  j = 1;
  y = j + 1;
  pages[y] = pages[j].slice(2);
  
  $(".output").text(j + " ::: " + (pages[2] != undefined) + " ::: " + (pages[y] != undefined));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="output">text</div>
```

> j = 1; y = j + 1;
>
> console.log(j + " ::: " + (pages[2] != undefined) + " ::: " +
>   (pages[y] != undefined));

returns 1 ::: false ::: true

This bug has got me.  I can't figure out why the same number used in these two different ways has a different result.  It's causing me a headache.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle that shows this?

Comment: What is `pages`? If it really is an array (or even an object), this is not possible to reproduce with the current code. See it returning "_1 ::: true ::: true_" at [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L7h8epd5/).

Comment: You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to produce a runnable demonstration of your issue here on Stack Overflow so that people don't have to go to a separate site.

Comment: 1)  Log content var pages and send the results? or even better send an snippet
2)  Also try this: !(pages[2]===undefined) instead of (pages[2]!=undefined)
2.1) and !(pages[y]===undefined) instead of (pages[y]!=undefined)
3) Also try this: !(typeof pages[2]==="undefined") instead of (pages[2]!=undefined)
3.1)and !(typeof pages[y]==="undefined") instead of (pages[y]!=undefined)

Comment: It's declared as an array.  I've run it in fiddle but it doesn't do the same thing.

Comment: @BrettGrentell - then something else is going on in the code. Perhaps `y` is not really what you think it is?

Comment: You've to post a full reproducable example here, without it the question is not answerable. Most likely `y` is not what you think it is, but why, we can't say without seeing the real code you have.

Comment: y is exactly what I have above.

Comment: and for some reason I can't reproduce it in fiddle or on here

Comment: Did you check the value in that same logging? A bit aside, but you really should declare your variables.

Comment: I thought that maybe it's the syntax between using pages[2] and pages[y].  They are both the same value but produce different outputs.  As far as I'm concerned 1 + 1 = 2

Comment: @BrettGrentell - If you log `y` in your current log statement (the one that's producing weird issues) - what does it log? Is it `2`?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that 'j' above was actually a string.  I didn't convert to an integer after reading from $().attr().